# Comparison method violates its general contract in some circumstances

Tags: java, android

I am using this code to sort items by date:

```
Collections.sort(productList, (d1, d2) -> {

            if (d1.getDateExpired() == null && d2.getDateExpired() == null) {
                return 1;
            } else if (d1.getDateExpired() == null && d2.getDateExpired() != null) {
                return 1;
            } else if (d1.getDateExpired() != null && d2.getDateExpired() == null) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return d1.getDateExpired().compareTo(d2.getDateExpired());
            }

        })
```

I know there are some answers, but i cannot understand the bug, especially that I am cannot reproduce the issue, it happen to 2 user out of ~300.

Comment: If both are nulls why do you want to return 1 instead of 0? What is the point of swapping them? If at some point after many swapping instead of comparing a,b you will end up comparing b,a you will get a<b and then b<a.

Comment: Anyway your lambda can probably be replaced with `Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(YourClass:getDateExpired))` or `Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(YourClass:getDateExpired))` depending what you want to achieve.

Comment: I should push items without date to the end of the list, probably i did something wrong

Comment: @PavelPoley *"probably i did something wrong"* See [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227943/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-in-some-circumstances#comment104669437_59227943). The first `return` statement should be `return 0;`

Comment: @Andreas I will try, although i have no way to reproduce

Comment: At this moment when your comparator compares any item without date to itself it returns 1, which means items are not equal to themselves.

Comment: "I should push items without date to the end of the list" in that case `Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(YourClass::getDateExpired))` should be enough to achieve it (I missed additional `:` in previous example).